# Kafka JDBC Sink Connector - Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am creating jdbc sink connector(confluent) to oracle, first time. Below is the connector config. It is not creating and loading the table, but offset is being increased as per log and no error thrown in the log. Please suggest what could be the issue.

Producing through java, 5 sample records. I have tried curl to check the status, it is running.

```
{
    "name": "ora_sink_task",
    "config": {
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/servicename",
            "connection.user": "user",
            "connection.password": "password",
            "topics": "connecttest",
            "tasks.max": "1",
            "table.name.format": "member_cbdt_sink1",
            "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
            "auto.create": "true"
            }
}
```

Connector log:

> [2019-09-09 00:34:23,832] INFO Checking Oracle dialect for existence
>   of table "member_cbdt_sink1"
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.OracleDatabaseDialect:492)
>   [2019-09-09 00:34:23,834] INFO Using Oracle dialect table
>   "member_cbdt_sink1" absent
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.OracleDatabaseDialect:500)
>   [2019-09-09 00:34:23,846] INFO Checking Oracle dialect for existence
>   of table "member_cbdt_sink1"
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.OracleDatabaseDialect:492)
>   [2019-09-09 00:34:23,849] INFO Using Oracle dialect table
>   "member_cbdt_sink1" present
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.OracleDatabaseDialect:500)
>   [2019-09-09 00:34:24,037] INFO Setting metadata for table
>   "member_cbdt_sink1" to Table{name='"member_cbdt_sink1"',
>   columns=[Column{'first_name', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false,
>   sqlType=CLOB}, Column{'height', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false,
>   sqlType=BINARY_FLOAT}, Column{'last_name', isPrimaryKey=false,
>   allowsNull=false, sqlType=CLOB}, Column{'age', isPrimaryKey=false,
>   allowsNull=false, sqlType=NUMBER}, Column{'automated_email',
>   isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=NUMBER}, Column{'weight',
>   isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=BINARY_FLOAT}]}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.TableDefinitions:65) [2019-09-09
>   00:35:13,775] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=ora_sink_task-0} Committing
>   offsets asynchronously using sequence number 1:
>   {connecttest-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=55, metadata=''}}
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:345) [2019-09-09
>   01:03:13,775] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=ora_sink_task-0} Committing
>   offsets asynchronously using sequence number 29:
>   {connecttest-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=60, metadata=''}}
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:345)

Comment: Any suggestions on this?  first_name is the string in java producer schema, but in connector metadata, it seems CLOB, Could it cause any issue? if so, how to handle it.?

Answer (score 1):

It worked by changing the value of table.name.format from lowercase to uppercase as Oracle looks for uppercase seems.